# Does use of shared memory cause error in this code?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I'm using Tesla k40c gpu. I run the following code on it:

```
 #define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

  __global__ void ker(float * a, float * c,long long cor_size,int n, int m)
    {
    extern __shared__ float cache[];
    cache[threadIdx.x]=4;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int  m =500,n =10000;
        long long cor_size = n-1;
        cor_size *=n;
        cor_size /=2;
        float * dev_bold1,*dev_bold3;
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold1,sizeof(float)*m*n));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold3,sizeof(float)*cor_size));
        float * bold1 = new float [m*n];
        memset(bold1, 0, sizeof(float)*m*n);
        float * bold3 = new float [cor_size];
        memset(bold3, 0, sizeof(float) *cor_size);
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy( dev_bold1, bold1, sizeof(float) * m  * n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        ker<<<cor_size,m,m>>>(dev_bold1,dev_bold3,cor_size,n,m);
        gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
        gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(bold3, dev_bold3, sizeof(float)*cor_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    return 1;
    }
```

After running code I got the following error:

> GPUassert: an illegal memory access was encountered test2.cu 48

Line 48 refers to

> gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(bold3, dev_bold3, sizeof(float)*cor_size,
>   cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

I don't understand what causes the error but when I change the value of m to something like 50 or fewer code works, but for higher values, it gives me this error. Is this issue related to the use of shared memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third kernel launch parameter should be `m*sizeof(float)`. That parameter specifies the size of the shared memory in *bytes*.